# modrewrite regex

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Can somebody help me? I need to regex 2 variables:

locale = 2 letters, reference = 6 digits

```
# http://www.site.com/fr/123456/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$([0-9]{6})/?$ includes/redirect.php?loc=$1&ref=$2 [L]
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: my RewriteRule is not correct, I need to capture both vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{6})/?$ includes/redirect.php?loc=$1&ref=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Ah... Possibly add a / just after ^. Edited answer.

Comment: Mmmm the examples I see are not showing that. I'll try to test it.

Comment: sorry it does work, I have a conflict with an earlier rules: RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ $1?locale=en_GB [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^it/(.*)$ $1?locale=it_IT [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ $1?locale=fr_FR [NC,L]

Comment: Ok, I've tested it and it should work.
Check that `includes/redirect.php` really matches an existing file. Where is your rewrite rule ? in `httpd.conf` ? in a `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Yeah it's working now all together, I just put my earlier (conflicting) rules under these new ones and all set. Thank so much for the help :-))